# problem with dead keys (acute, diaeresis, etc) c++

Tags: c++, x11, xlib

I'm currently writing my own virtual keyboard for linux using the X11 lib and i just can't find the way to simulate a KeyPress event of any dead keys. 
I'd tried , for example, to write "á" using the asigned macro, which is XK_aacute, and nothing happens.
later i'd tried to send XK_acute (the acute accent macro) and then XK_a, and again, nothing happens :(

In the KDE virtual Keyboard "Kvkbd" it's possible to do this, so i downloaded the source code, but it only supports the english keyboard layout

Here is my test code:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
 Display *display;
 unsigned int keycode;
 unsigned int keycode1;
 display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

 keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_aacute); 
 XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode, True, 0);
 XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode, False, 0);

 keycode1 = XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_acute);
 XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode1, True, 0);


 keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_a);
 XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode, True, 0);
 XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode, False, 0);

 XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode1, False, 0);


 keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_D);
 XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode, True, 0);
 XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode, False, 0);
 XFlush(display);
}
```

Any help or idea will be much apreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i just figured out ¬¬

```
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
 Display *display;
 unsigned int keycode;
 unsigned int keycode1;
 display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

 keycode1 = XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_dead_acute);
 XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode1, true, 0);


 keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_A);
 XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode, true, 0);
 XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode, false, 0);

 XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode1, false, 0);

 XFlush(display);
}
```

i was using the wrong macro