# How can I get the KeyCode associated to a given KeySym?

Tags: c, keyboard, xlib

I have seen that `XGetKeyboardMapping()` would let me do that, but the documentation is opaque and I haven’t been able to find any examples. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for:

> KeyCode [XKeysymToKeycode](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/keyboard/XKeysymToKeycode.html)(display, keysym)
>         Display *display;
>         KeySym keysym;

`keycode1 = XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_dead_acute);`

[Also see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2391650/390913)

Comment: jesus… I have spent more than 10 hours battling against that mapping thing. Thank you :)